# Can I store Python function on a MongoDB collection?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using Python dicts to map functions:

```
def linear(a, x, b):
    return a * x + b


def quadratic(a, x, b, c):
    return a * x * x + b * x + c


sensor = {
    'id': 'aaaaa',
    'name': 'temp001',
    'quantity': 'temperature',
    'unit': 'C',
    'charlength': 4,
    'convert': {
        'linear': linear(3, 2, 6),
        'quadratic': quadratic(2, 4, 7, 8)
    }
}
```

But when I use MongoDB to store the dict on a collection, the result that I get is only a string and not a function call.

How can I convert it? I've read that using `exec` or `eval` is not very safe?

Comment: What would you expect the result to be? What would you do/how would you want to work with the data if you could store "the function call"?

Comment: @deceze By now, when I iterate the dict, I can call the function through .itervalues() method. I would like to do the same.

Comment: @Hugo you are not storing the functions in the dict but the results of them instead.

Comment: `.itervalues` doesn't call anything. As written, the function is called immediately and its result is stored in the dict, at no point are you "storing the function". Try `{"foo": linear(3, 2, 6)}` in the interactive Python REPL and you'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
sensor = {
    'id': 'aaaaa',
    'name': 'temp001',
    'quantity': 'temperature',
    'unit': 'C',
    'charlength': 4,
    'convert': {
        'linear': ("linear", 3, 2, 6),
        'quadratic': ("quadratic", 2, 4, 7, 8)
    }
}
```

And upon retrieval, you could do:

```
linear_function = sensor["convert"]["linear"]

globals()[linear_function[0]](*linear_function[1:])
```

And access the function via a string parameter instead of using `eval()` which is plain risky.

And to make it even less chunky, since you're already storing the function name as a key, you could do:

```
sensor = {
    'id': 'aaaaa',
    'name': 'temp001',
    'quantity': 'temperature',
    'unit': 'C',
    'charlength': 4,
    'convert': {
        'linear': (3, 2, 6),
        'quadratic': (2, 4, 7, 8)
    }
}

linear_function_parameters = sensor["convert"]["linear"]
globals()["linear"](*linear_function_parameters)
```

or even

```
for function in sensor['convert']:
    variables = sensor['convert'][function]
    result = globals()[function](*variables)
```

Which would make it fully dynamic.
This way you'd only have to store traditional lists and strings in MongoDB, but you could easily access the defined functions in your script.